# Hyperlink to worksheet field by name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a hyperlink from one worksheet(Home) to another worksheet(Events details), finding the target cell by the value.

```
"Home":
A
[MyLink]

"Events details"
A
["hello there"]
```

So "MyLink" should point to "hello there" independent of the position of "hello there" in A column.

What I tried: I could create a hyper link to a specific cell with

```
HYPERLINK("#'Events details'!A2")
```

I could find a position of "hello there" using:

```
=MATCH("hello there", 'Events details'!$A:$A, 0)
```

so I tried putting it together

```
HYPERLINK("#'Events details'!MATCH("hello there", 'Events details'!$A:$A, 0)")
```

but it does not seems to work

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Events details'!A"&MATCH("hello there",'Events details'!A:A,),"DisplayText")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the formula that you tried to use is that excel does not evaluate text strings (stuff between quotes). What I mean by that, can be seen below:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Events details'!MATCH("hello there", 'Events details'!$A:$A, 0)")
           ^------------------------^           ^----------------------------^
```

Excel first interprets the first part above as text `"#'Events details'!MATCH("`, followed by a command supposedly called `hello there` and then another text `", 'Events details'!$A:$A, 0)"` because of the way the quotes work.

But this, as you have seen will not give you anything useful.

What you will have to do is concatenate the sheetname, and the cell address (which has the column name and row number). Since you already know that the column name is A, you know that the full cell address should be something like `"#'Events details'!A_"` where the underscore here is meant to be some number you will retrieve using `MATCH`. For this first part, your `HYPERLINK` function becomes:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Events details'!A"   )
```

Since `MATCH` returns the row number, you will have to put it afterwards (notice that the whole `MATCH` function is outside any quotes):

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Events details'!A"MATCH("hello there", 'Events details'!$A:$A, 0))
```

But wait! Excel doesn't understand that the two 'parts' above should become one, so you have to use something to concatenate the two parts, the shorter way being by using the `&`:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Events details'!A"&MATCH("hello there", 'Events details'!$A:$A, 0))
```

Or you can use the longer function:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#'Events details'!A",MATCH("hello there", 'Events details'!$A:$A, 0)))
```

And of course, you can use the optional second input of the `HYPERLINK` function to give the link a 'friendly name' as Excel calls it.